# FORMULA FIELD DATE FIELD WORKING DAYS

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have 2 date fields which calculates the number of working days of 2 date fields. here's my forula:

```
((DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c ) - (DATEVALUE( Date_Test_Field__c )))) - 

(CASE(MOD( DATEVALUE(Application_Received_Date__c ) - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
0 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c ) - DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ), 7),1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,1,6,2,0), 
1 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c ) - DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ), 7),0,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,2,2), 
2 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c  ) - DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ), 7),0,0,1,0,2,0,3,1,2), 
3 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c ) - DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ), 7),0,0,1,0,2,1,2), 
4 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c ) - DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ), 7),0,0,1,1,2), 
5 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c ) - DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ), 7),0,1,2), 
6 , CASE( MOD( DATEVALUE( Application_Received_Date__c ) - DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ), 7),6,2,1), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR(( (DATEVALUE(Application_Received_Date__c )) - (DATEVALUE(Date_Test_Field__c ))) /7) * 2))
```

Can somebody tell me how to change the return value to Seconds, Minutes and Hours.. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's a horrible mess. If you format it so people can read it, they might be able to help you.

Comment: my appolgies i forgot to edit

Comment: Ooh that's sooo much nicer :)

Comment: So... for seconds you multiply the result * 86400. minutes is result * 1440. hours is result * 24